# Add border around specific rows in a Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

```
  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6
  Row11 Row12 Row13 Row14 Row15 Row16
  Row21 Row22 Row23 Row24 Row25 Row26
  Row31 Row32 Row33 Row34 Row35 Row36
```

I wish to add a border around the entire row or a specific row, column combination (Col4) for which first column values are equal. For example, if Row11 is equal to Row21, then either there should be a border around those two rows or around Row14, Row24.
Would highly appreciate if anyone can provide any recommendations around the same.

Comment: Could you clarify " if Row11 is equal to Row21, then either there should be a border around those two rows"?
Your columns are named, but you don't have "rows", what you've labelled are elements. Do you want the border around matching elements or around a row containing matching elements?

Comment: I need to know a few things to help.  How are you presenting the data in the web service? Are you laying out the table in the DOM with JSP or are you delivering it via a JSON AJAX service with jquery? Have you figured out how you are going to identify matches? For instance will the server side do that either as part of the query or in the presentation or are you looking to do that in javascript on the client?  If you are unsure, tell us more about what you have so far or if you are looking for an approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not hard to iterate over the first cell of each row to determine if the cell content is "equal" to the content of the first cell in the following row, so you could easily have a function to return an array of the matching rows, e.g.

```
// Return an array of arrays of row indexes 
// whose first cell content is equal
function getMatchingRows(table) {
  var rows = table.rows;
  var allMatches = [];
  var currentMatches, currentValue, previousValue;

  for (var i=0, iLen=rows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    currentValue = getText(rows[i].cells[0]);

    if (currentValue == previousValue) {

      if (!currentMatches) {
        currentMatches = [i-1, i];
      } else {
        currentMatches.push(i);
      }

    } else {
      previousValue = currentValue;

      if (currentMatches) {
        allMatches.push(currentMatches);
        currentMatches = null;
      }
    }
  }
  return allMatches;
}

// Simple function to return element's text content
function getText(el) {
  if (typeof el.textContent == 'string') {
    return el.textContent;
  } else if (typeof el.innerText == 'string') {
    return el.innerText;
  }
}
```

Now it's just a matter of applying the appropriate style to the cells, so you need a *hightlighRows* function that hightlights rows based on a row index array, and a *hightlightColumnSegment* that highlights cells based on the same row index array and a cell index (or perhaps multiple cell indexes if you want to highlight blocks of adjacent columns and rows).

The *getText* function is very simplistic, but sufficient for the example.

Answer (score 1):

You have a **jsp** tag, I assume you are rendering this table server-side and the logic you described is also server-side. May I suggest adding a class called "highlight" or something to the `<td>` you want to highlight and then style it in your CSS accordingly, for example:

```
.highlight
{
   border:1px solid #000;
}
```